# How to delete part of URL using .htaccess and redirecting every time to a specific file

Tags: php, .htaccess, webserver

I'm setting up in the same machine two different web application and I want to change the `.htaccess` file in that way that it will work without having the need to have a new domain in my server. More exactly I want to delete parts of URL.

In the `/var/www/html/` directory I have two different web apps

`/var/www/html/
│---webapp1/
│   │---public/
│   │   │---index.php
│   │---.htaccess
│---webapp2/
│   │---public/
│   │   │---index.php
│   │---.htaccess`

The `index.php` checks the URL

```
$url = explode('/', trim($request));
$this->controller = isset($url[0]) ? $url[0].'Controller':'loginController';
```

So if I would have in the root folder only one web app it would work. But now my URL is domain.com/webapp1/public/ I want to remove `/webapp1/public/` part from URL.

My `.htaacess` file in both web apps looks like:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
```

If I change my `000-default.conf` to:

```
DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/webapp1/public/"
<Directory "/var/www/html//webapp1/public/">
</Directory>
```

it works for the `webapp1`.

I have tried to change `.htaccess` for webapp1 to:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^.*$ /webapp1/public/index.php [QSA,L]
```

but it doesn't work.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: _Why_ are you against a “proper” setup using separate virtual hosts?

Comment: @04FS By virtual hosts, you mean having for each one subdomain?

Comment: This is a bit confusing an all over the place. First you say this stuff is located under `/var/www/html/`, now you show a document root pointing at `C:/xampp/htdocs/webapp1/public/` - now which one is it? Are you on a unix or a windows machine? And did you _keep_ your changes you made to the httpd.conf and tried something with the .htaccess afterwards, or did you reverse the first change again?

Comment: Subdomains or “top level” domain would be up to you, but Yes, this should rather use two separate virtual hosts if at all possible, and if those apps have nothing to do with each other in the first place.

Comment: @04FS I'm on UNIX, so I updated the paths. When I changed my `.htaccess`, I left the `000-default.conf` as it was. And these two Web Apps have nothing to do with each other. I will add in `/var/www/html/` a simple HTML file that will redirect the user in one of the apps.